# VS2005 crashes often when compiling

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, linker, crash, visual-studio-2005

I can change one small thing commenting/un-commenting it and VS2005 will either crash or not crash for no additional reason in either case.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  8.0.50727.867
  Application Timestamp:    45d2c842
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0646
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b8f
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000ce6c3
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0646
  Additional Information 2: 06468f0034e46fb7e5e65a0a8a306ffb
  Additional Information 3: 9aba
  Additional Information 4: 9abaaa502ccb3837971bddc9d127747d
```

Since the above is really of no help to me, is there some way I can diagnose what's going on? All I'm able to get out of debugging the compile crash (in VS2005) that is that there is a corrupted heap.

Comment: Try using safe-mode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.80).aspx) could be a plugin

Comment: What counts as a third party plugin? I may need to be using some. Could it be related to IntelliSense updating when I start the compile?

Comment: Add-ins and extensions under tool menu. Could be anything, disable all and enable one-at-a-time to see which one couses you trouble.

Comment: I tried /SafeMode but it didn't do anything - don't have any plugins. I also tried compatibility layers for XP/Vista. XP crashed 100% on intellisense updates but vista seems to be stable for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehh.. Solution: Get rid of the outdated buggy IDE and upgrade to a more recent one. Went to [VSC15](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). No crashes since.

Answer (score 0):

Some options you can try out:

- You can get a log when booting Visual Studio using `/log` as attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272(v=vs.80).aspx

- Creating a crash dump

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/07/25/678308.aspx

- Uninstall ReSharpen (if you use it)
- Reinstall Visual Studio
- Create a new Windows User and see if you get the same trouble